# Access Web Site W/O Including Port

Tags: portforwarding, dyndns, ultidev

I have a Asp.net website hosted through Ultidev, and am using DynDns to assign a hostname (web address) to the site.  My question is, is their a setting or configuration or something that I can change to go to www.yoursitename.org and my page load?  Or must you always specify the port to connect to in order to connect to your site www.yoursitename.org:12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already configured your router to forward port 80 (standard http port) traffic to you host computer, and opened PC firewall to allow inbound port 80 connections, then what you need to do is to run "`[UltiDev Web Server Explorer][1]`" and there add combination of the www.yoursitename.org and port 80 as shown on the screenshots below. One thing to note that if port 80 is already occupied in the exclusive mode by an another web server (Apache, etc.), you will see that when saving UWS configuration, the www.yoursitename.org:80 will disappear. If it didn't disappear, then the site:port combination was available and now will be used.
[image]
[image]